# Jplayer radio should be paused

Tags: javascript, audio-streaming, playback, jplayer, internet-radio

I have a problem in my Jplayer. It has to be paused after 30 seconds so it can work properly. I don't know why this happens or how to solve it. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

my radio URL: https://2mdotnet.com/portal/business/cms/radio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't connect to your stream at all to help you debug this, but if it is working for you, it sounds like the server isn't flushing a large buffer of data to the client upon connect.

If you have a live radio stream, it is common for the server to keep a buffer (around 1MB or so) so that when a client connects, the server will fill the client buffer as quickly as possible, allowing the client to start playback as soon as possible.

Also, is there any particular reason you're serving the stream over HTTPS?  While this will work in browsers, other players will have difficulty.  In addition, there is extra overhead for sending the stream this way.  If you don't need HTTPS for the stream, I recommend not using it.

Comment: What is your OS/browser? 
You can check it on http://www.big4fun.com/radio.php 

It works with no problems on IOS and Android. But on PC, it should be paused and has the problem I've mentioned in my question. Have exactly no idea why this happen :S Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Ah, that URL you posted is not the URL of your stream.  Your stream URL is actually  http://184.107.17.34:8006.

Comment: Well, how can I solve the problem? If you have any idea, please help.

Comment: @Iman, I've tested your stream in Chrome, and did not have the problem you are having.  Your server buffer is also working correctly.  I think the problem is your connection.

Comment: It works correctly for 40 seconds then it begins to have a problem after that.

Comment: Well, the problem is solved when I removed the introduction file from the server.